# reasons for deadlock in producer/consumer and debugging

Tags: java, multithreading

Though the below is well known topic I want Your ideas please.
I had written a small program as below: All the producers are queued up and also the consumers. I couldn't understand why it is so. What are the scenarios where it can block completely.

Let us consider Producers/consumers are waiting for lock on array and what making consumers /producers to exit out the synchronized block. I mean it has to move atleast slowly but deadlock must not happen. I believe.

Here I have 2 questions:
1. What are the scenarios that deadlock is happening.
2. How to understand what is happening under the hood. I mean how to debug.

```
public class ProducerConsumer implements Runnable {

    boolean producer = false;

    private volatile int i = 0;

    int[] array = new int[10];

    public static String getThreadName() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

    public void producer() {
        try {
            synchronized (array) {
                while (i > 9) {
                    System.out.println("Producer of " + getThreadName()
                            + " is waiting i " + i);
                    array.wait();
                    System.out.println("Producer of " + getThreadName()
                            + " came out of sleep i " + i);
                }
                System.out.println("Producer of " + getThreadName()
                        + " in synchronized block i" + i);
                array[i] = generateRandom();
                System.out.println("Producer of " + getThreadName()
                        + " inserted in array " + array[i] + " index " + i);
                i++;
                array.notifyAll();
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Producer of " + getThreadName()
                    + " interrupted " + e);
        }

    }

    public void consumer() {
        try {
            synchronized (array) {
                while (i < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer of " + getThreadName()
                            + " is waiting i " + i);
                    array.wait();
                    System.out.println("Consumer of " + getThreadName()
                            + " came out of sleep i " + i);
                }
                System.out.println("Consumer of " + getThreadName()
                        + " in synchronized block extracted value " + array[i]
                        + " of index " + i);
                i--;
                array.notifyAll();
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Consumer of " + getThreadName()
                    + " interrupted " + e);
        }

    }

    public static int generateRandom() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerConsumer pc = new ProducerConsumer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                new Thread(pc, "producer thread").start();
            else {
                new Thread(pc, "consumer thread").start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (getThreadName().equalsIgnoreCase("producer thread")) {
                producer();
            } else {
                consumer();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It struck as below output:

```
Consumer of consumer thread in synchronized block extracted value 0 of index 0
Producer of producer thread in synchronized block i-1
Producer of producer thread in synchronized block i-1
Consumer of consumer thread is waiting i -1
Consumer of consumer thread is waiting i -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect in many places.

I expect that all threads just finish with exceptions, either because of

- IllegalMonitorException (calling notify() on ProducerConsumer object
  but there is no synchronized block on this ProducerConsumer object)
- ArrayIndexOfBoundsException (i can become 10 in produce() method)

Have you checked error output?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I synchronized on array and waiting on other object.Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you edited your code - changed Thread.sleep() to wait(). It won't work either - wait() from produce() is called first and notify() from consume() will never be called.

Comment: There are no exceptions, now I changed wait and notify on array object as edited above. Still the same deadlock.

Comment: One more problem - you should check value of i inside synchronized block, otherwise it could be changed before entering synchronized block

Comment: and one more thing - you should use notifyAll() and check condition in a cycle (e.g. while (i < 9) { ... }).

Comment: btw, wait() should be called from synchronized block as well

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right and changed inside the synchronized block. But Again deadlock.

Comment: yes thats right it must be while not if because i might have changed in the meanwhile after wait.Did all changes still deadlock.

Comment: Because you always run produce() before consume() in the same thread it could be that all threads are stuck in wait() from produce(). Try using different threads for calling produce and consume.

Comment: Hi Kostya thank you very much for taking time. I changed the code as above. Still deadlock. Now I reduced the threads to 4 to understand better. From debugger What I found is 2 producers are waiting for acquiring locks but don't have clue why consumer threads are not proceeding and also which thread is holding the lock and why it is not releasing.

Comment: With your code above you should be getting exceptions again. The reason is that in consume() i can become negative (-1) and in produce you will access array[-1]. You should change your consume() method to check i<=0 and decrement i before consuming an element. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Instead of i<=0 i can make a check in the producer to increment i++ because a[0] must be removed and need not be the condition for wait.

Answer (score 0):

Java provides a neat implementation of concurrent programs via its `java.util.concurrent` package. So rather than trying to reinvent the wheel, and getting it all wrong, you should use the `Concurrent API` to handle locking in a safer way. Here's a simulation of a `Producer-Consumer`:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * We want a Producer thread to create random values, and the Consumer thread to
 * consume it. One caveat is that if the Producer has already created a random
 * value, which the Consumer thread hasn't consumed yet, the Producer thread
 * blocks or waits. On the flip side, the Consumer thread waits for the Producer
 * thread to produce some value if the Producer thread hasn't already.
 * <p/>
 * Write a Program to simulate such a situation.
 */

public class ProducerConsumerCommunication
{
  private volatile boolean running = true;
  private ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> buffer = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
  private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

  public ProducerConsumerCommunication()
  {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    service.execute(new ProducerTask());
    service.execute(new ConsumerTask());
    service.shutdown();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new ProducerConsumerCommunication();
  }

  private class ProducerTask implements Runnable
  {
    public void run()
    {
      while (running)
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
          Integer value = random.nextInt();
          buffer.put(value); // Blocks if buffer is full.
          System.out.println("Value Put: " + value);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private class ConsumerTask implements Runnable
  {
    public void run()
    {
      while (running)
      {
        try
        {
          Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
          Integer value = buffer.take(); // Blocks if buffer is empty.
          System.out.println("Value Taken: " + value);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try running it and see for yourself as to how easy and intuitive it is to implement such scenarios using the Concurrent API. It also keeps your code clean and lets you focus on the problem at hand.

Reasons for deadlock in `Producer Consumer` problem aren't that many. If one thread has lock on an `object A` and is waiting for lock on `object B` to be released, while if other thread has lock on `object B` at the same time and is waiting for lock on `object A` to be released, deadlock situation arises.

Comment: Hi Aman you are right we can don't have to reinvent the wheel But here I'm interested in why it should fail.Any way thank you very much for taking time in answering.